# php encrypt and decrypt

Tags: php, hyperlink, encryption

can anyone tell me how to encrypt and decrypt a URL string ?

I want to encrypt a hyperlink ...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "encrypt"? What do you want to do with the link?

Comment: example I have the following link :

http://localhost/waterwell/e_book.php?flnm8=New Folder\PhotoPlus Reg.txt

I want to change the [New Folder\PhotoPlus Reg.txt] into something that is encrypted.. so that ppl won't see the actual path...

Comment: i read the file direct from server directory.....
what i want is something like this :
The encrytped URL shows this:
localhost/waterwell/e_book.php?flnm8=werf182hvd
but when they click on the link, it will decrpt the werf182hvd convert to the actual filename which is New Folder\PhotoPlus Reg.txt

Answer (score 1):

If you can use database,you could create a table to map a file to an id.

Create a 'mapping_table'

```
id - integer
file_location - string
```

Your URL would look something like `localhost/waterwell/e_book.php?id=12` .

Answer (score 0):

make links that return to your server with querystring GET params identifying the file. the server  can then do `echo file_get_contents()` after you figure out which  file from the inputs

In your example it's trivial. simply omit the portion of the url you don't want shown and fill it back in on the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $confirmpassword = $_POST['confirmpassword'];
            $value_check = true;
            $ciphering = "AES-128-CTR";
            $options = 0; 
            $encryption_iv = '1234567891011121'; 
            $encryption_key = "GeeksforGeeks";
            $confirmpasswordencryption = openssl_encrypt($confirmpassword, $ciphering,$encryption_key, $options, $encryption_iv);  

$encryption = "pABqPJhobIMHzqai"
                                                        $ciphering = "AES-128-CTR";
                                                        $options = 0;
                                                        $decryption_iv = '1234567891011121'; 
  
// Store the decryption key 
$decryption_key = "GeeksforGeeks"; 
  
// Use openssl_decrypt() function to decrypt the data 
$decryption=openssl_decrypt ($encryption, $ciphering,  
        $decryption_key, $options, $decryption_iv); 
  
// Display the decrypted string 
echo "Decrypted String: " . $decryption;
```

Comment: **Security warning - the code above is using a static initialization vector (IV) that makes the complete encryption UNSECURE**. Kindly use a randomly generated iv that is prepended to the ciphertext, thanks.